# Cleanest method of inter-program communication on separate devices

Tags: python, c++, julia, cross-platform, interprocess

I need to settle on a method of communication between multiple programs spread out over multiple machines. The data itself is fairly straight forwards, comprising of variable length vectors with some meta-data descriptors.

Each program "type" will send data to 1 other program type, and expects to see a reply from it.

The number of connections a given program has is variable over time, and programs can be added or removed at any moment.

Programs may be distributed across several processors, which may use different operating systems, or could be microprocessors.

[image: Example program structure]

I have not had to really contend with such a inter-communication puzzle before and am unsure of what the cleanest approach would be. I've heard that ROS might be useful, but that it may not be suitable for Windows environments and has a steep learning curve. I can imagine creating a database between the nodes which would act as a kind of blackboard, but this feels like it may be very inefficient. If using sockets would resolve efficiencies, then how would the connections be managed / maintained?

My main development environment at the moment is Julia, but I can port the data over to C++ or Python without too much discomfort.

I am open to ideas and learning new things, but I can't figure out which path to take. Any nuggets of wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

---

As requested in a comment, here is some additional information:

- Data: The data is a vector of floating point numbers, which can vary in size anywhere from 1 value to 1000's of values (maybe more depending on other aspects of the project, but I'm capping it for prototyping purposes). The meta-data is in json format and provides information such as the total length of the array, and a few identifiers (all integers).
- Reliability: I can handle a few missed messages here and there. I'd need the data in the order it was sent though. So if a packet of data arrives after a more recent one it will be ignored. (In case you were instead referring to data integrity, then the data must not be corrupted in transit).
- Latency: As little as possible as the program could start to introduce errors otherwise. That being said, for prototyping purposes I can persevere with 10's of milliseconds average, and irregular 100's of milliseconds. I would very much like to keep this down though.
- Standard IP Facilities: You may assume all devices have these, yes.

Comment: since the data seems to be structured by which machines it can go to, i'd suggest a classic server/client setup with sockets and an abstract interface

Comment: TCP socket, maybe?

Comment: Sounds like [Actors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). The only Julia implementation I could find, though, is rather outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps taking a look at something well established (and therefore should be able to hook up to whichever language/s you end up using) like Redis or RabbitMQ would be wise seeing as you'll need to be able to communicate with a number of different devices over a network. Either way having some form of central hub that handles communication among the other devices would be advisable.

Comment: Agree with the "Don't reinvent the wheel" of the bulk of the answer, but there's too little information to be able to tell whether the last sentence really is advisable.

Comment: @p1nnz thanks for the heads up on Redis and RabbitMQ. RabbitMQ in particular looks like it might fit the bill for a lot of my use cases.